# Current of inductor in parallel to resistor

Tags: current, resistors, inductor

When a resistor and an inductor are in series, by simple writing down all the voltages and using integral, the current of the inductor could be calculated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRlIa1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$ v - IR - L (dI/dt) = 0\$

\$ I(t) = (V/R) * (1 - e^{-tR/L}) \$

But in the circuit shown below, writing the voltages doesn't do much help since when I use integral on the equation, the charge of the inductor appears (integral of current by time) which I don't have any answer for and don't think is part of the equation. So how should I try to find the formula for the current of the inductor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6yRwZ.png)</sup>

Comment: The solution you've written for the first circuit cannot be correct; the steady state \$(t \rightarrow \infty)\$ current is, by inspection (replace the inductor with a wire), \$V/R\$.  But your solution gives a steady state current of zero.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've replaced the correct formula.

Comment: That's better and it's correct if the initial current (the current at \$t = 0\$) is zero but there is a more general solution:  $$i(t) = \frac{V}{R} + \left(I_0 - \frac{V}{R} \right)e^{-tR/L}$$  where \$I_0\$ is the initial current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any solutions beside using the Norton or Thevenin
>   equivalence theorems?

Yes, if you know the solution for the first circuit, you can reason out the solution to the second.

The correct solution to the first circuit is:

$$i(t) = \frac{V}{R} + \left(I_0 - \frac{V}{R} \right)e^{-tR/L}$$

where \$I_0\$ is the initial current (the current when \$t = 0\$).

Since, like the first circuit, there is one inductor, the solution will be of the form

$$i_L(t) = I_{ss} + \left(I_0 - I_{ss} \right)e^{-t/\tau}$$

where \$I_{ss}\$ is the steady state current (the current for \$t \rightarrow \infty\$)

The steady state current is (replace the inductor with a wire) easily found to be

$$I_{ss} = \frac{V}{R_1}$$

The time constant \$\tau\$ is found by zeroing the voltage source and finding the equivalent resistance the inductor 'sees' which is the two resistors in parallel

$$R_{eq} = R_1||R_2$$

and so

$$\tau = \frac{L}{R_1||R_2}$$

---

Of course, one could do this the hard way 'from scratch' and write the ODE for the second circuit:

$$v_L = V - (i_{R_2} + i_L)R_1$$

$$i_{R_2} = \frac{v_L}{R_2}$$

$$\Rightarrow  v_L = V\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} - i_L R_1||R_2$$

$$v_L = L\frac{di_L}{dt}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{di_L}{dt} + \frac{R_1||R_2}{L}i_L = \frac{V}{L}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

You should solve this and verify that the solution is the same as what we reasoned to above.  Also, this is precisely the ODE you would write by inspection if you used the Thevenin equivalent circuit approach.

Answer (score 2):

> So how should I try to find the formula for the current of the
>   inductor?

Convert the voltage source (E), R1 and R2 to a smaller voltage source in series with the parallel combination of R1 and R2. The new smaller voltage source value is: -

\$\dfrac{R2}{R1+R2}\$ multiplied by E (the value of the original voltage source).

Theory - you can convert "E" to a current source in parallel with R1. (see [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/Norton.html) page for Norton's theorum).

Once you have converted it, R1 is in parallel with R2 so now you back-convert to a voltage source in series with R1||R2.

You are now back to a single voltage source in series with a single resistor feeding an inductor.

Comment: Are there any solutions beside using the Norton or Thevenin equivalence theorems?

Comment: I expect there are but why bother?

Comment: Because I can't find anything resembling those theorems in my pamphlet so my professors might not have actually taught them!

Comment: Well I don't have access to all the information inside your head and neither do I have the pamphlet you refer to so I can only give you what I see to be the most straightforward answer that makes sense to me.

Comment: No no don't get me wrong. I just asked if there's any other solution. Thank you for answering my question. I've given your answer "useful" feedback already :)

Comment: It shouldn't matter what method you use, as long as you get the correct answer. Most decent professors will see that and if you haven't been taught it, it should really be bonus points for the extra research you done. I made that point last year in one of my assignments where I thought the method taught to us was far too long winded so I simplified it and used a different method, which was viewed favourably...

Comment: Have you done superposition theory - you can prove Norton's from that.